# Magit log dates

Tags: magit

In Magit log buffer commits (one per line) are shown with relative date. This is nice for recent commits, but makes little sense for older changes. In particular, this makes it annoyingly hard to relate commit dates to specific date, e.g. to find answer to question "which change might have broken the release on 3rd of April?".

Is it possible to somehow change the way commit dates are shown? I only found `magit-duration-spec`, but that's not exactly what I need.

Answer (score 16):

This feature is now accessible through `magit-log-margin`. See [this ticket](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2792) and [this commit.](https://github.com/magit/magit/commit/186c3d6ccbca78386cb0faa69164b3396bb38ae6)

Comment: Is there an example of how this variable should be set to show absolute date?

Comment: @Liam I don't see any examples, but [here's a section about it in the manual.](https://magit.vc/manual/magit/Log-Margin.html#Log-Margin) Mine is set to `(t "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M " magit-log-margin-width t 18)`, which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVNfw.png) in the Customize interface and the date looks like [this as a result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjnuF.png)

Answer (score 14):

If you need to be sure about the author and/or commit date of a particular commit, then you can always just show that commit in a separate buffer by pressing <kbd>RET</kbd> with point on that commit in the log.

---

But that's not very convenient if you have to do it a lot of course. I have started working on making this more flexible.

Comment: I have the same problem and I'm glad to hear that you are working on this!

Comment: Indeed, it would be very nice to have a way to display absolute dates instead of durations

Comment: @tarsius Has this been implemented? I can't find a reference to it in the documentation. Thanks for Magit, it is amazing :)

Comment: No, I forgot about this. Could you please open a feature request, so it does not happen again.

Comment: @thatismatt The specific variable which has this feature now is `magit-log-margin`.