# magit log view showing summarized diffstats inline?

Tags: magit

I'm hoping to see summarized diff stats (number of files changed and total insertions/deletions) inline in the magit log view.

Currently if the diffstats option is enabled the log is rendered with each commit spanning multiple lines like:

```
* 17ec06b dotemacs move media bindings
| 
|  .emacs.d/ebpa.org | 18 +++++++++---------
|  1 file changed, 9 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)
|
```

I'm curious if it is currently possible to see/add summarized diff stats inline with the commit message.  Perhaps as an additional column like this:

```
* 17ec06b dotemacs move media bindings                         (1 file, +9, -9)
```

The compactness would help in visually scanning the log to identify commits which should be rebased.

Judging from the discussion on [Magit log dates](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/14483/magit-log-dates) I'm guessing this is not easily done yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Judging from the discussion on Magit log dates I'm guessing this is not easily done yet.

I'm afraid that's correct.